# IndexDB Uncaught Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase'

Tags: javascript, html, transactions, local-storage, indexeddb

I'm working in a login/sigup sistem, I have to take the value of some inputs to register them, but I have a problem.

The error is:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

And occur in this code line: "var data = active.transaction(["usuarios"], "readwrite");"

Can anyone help me with this? Here is my code:

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var dataBase = null;

function startDB(){

  dataBase = indexedDB.open("objectDb", 1);


  dataBase.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {

    var active = dataBase.result;


    var objectDb = active.createObjectStore("usuarios", {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement : true });


    objectDb.createIndex('index_nombre','nombre', {unique : false});
    objectDb.createIndex('index_user','usuario', {unique : true});
    objectDb.createIndex('index_correo','email', {unique : true});
    objectDb.createIndex('index_pass','pass', {unique : false});
  };

  dataBase.onsuccess = function (e) {
    alert("Base de datos cargada correctamente");

  };

  dataBase.onerror = function (e) {
    alert("Error cargando la base de datos");
  };
}

function add() {
  var active = dataBase.result;

  var data = active.transaction(["usuarios"], "readwrite");

  var objectDb = data.objectStore("usuarios");

  var request = objectDb.put({
    nombre: document.querySelector("#nombre").value,
    usuario: document.querySelector("#usuario").value,
    email: document.querySelector("#email").value,
    pass: documento.querySelector("#pass").value,
  });

  request.onerror = function (e) {
    alert(request.error.name + '\n\n' + request.error.message);
  };

  data.oncomplete = function (e) {
    document.querySelector("#nombre").value = "";
    document.querySelector("#usuario").value = "";
    document.querySelector("#email").value = "";
    document.querySelector("#pass").value = "";
    alert("Objeto agregado correctamente");
  };
}
```

This is my first project with indexedDB so I'm very noob. Sorry if this is

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was an error in the var objectDb, I put the D in lowercase and it worked.